# How can I mark a cli arg to be dependant on another arg existance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, dependencies, argparse

I am using python3.4
The question refers to the https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html package

If I want an arg `--with_extra_actions` to always acompany `--arg1` or `--arg2` and give an error message if one of those two is missing?

Examples:
`command --arg1 --with_extra_actions`  That should work
`command --arg2 --with_extra_actions`  That should work
`command --with_extra_actions` That should fail with informative error.

I am doing it right now in the code itself. No issue there, but is there an intrinsic way for the `argparse` lib to do this?

Comment: There's a mutually-exclusive grouping, but no mutually-inclusive one.  Subparsers work for some cases.  Otherwise, doing your own testing after parsing is your best option.

Comment: Sometimes we can define `--arg1` to take several arguments, 2, '+', etc. Then we don't need define extra actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [add_mutually_exclusive_group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group). Here example(test.py):

```
import argparse
import sys


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='our_cmd')
# with_extra_actions is always required
parser.add_argument(
    '--with_extra_actions',
    required=True,
    action='store_false'
)

# only one argument from group is available
# group is required - one from possible arguments is required
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--arg1', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('--arg2', action='store_true')

parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

Now let's check our script:

```
python test.py --with_extra_actions
usage: our_cmd [-h] --with_extra_actions (--arg1 | --arg2)
our_cmd: error: one of the arguments --arg1 --arg2 is required
```

Let's try with `arg1` and `arg2`:

```
python test.py --arg1 --arg2 --with_extra_actions
usage: our_cmd [-h] --with_extra_actions (--arg1 | --arg2)
our_cmd: error: argument --arg2: not allowed with argument --arg1
```

Without any errors:

```
python test.py --arg1 --with_extra_actions
python test.py --arg2 --with_extra_actions
```

Hope this helps.